# AES_ENCRYPT in mysql returns '

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using the following query to get AES encrypted value:

```
SELECT AES_ENCRYPT( 'REMYA UNNIKRISHNAN', 'nirvana1987' ) AS encString
```

and I'm getting the value as:

```
'UT�\Z��*���F��R�đtFn�X/�~J�
```

now when I try to enter this value to another table it shows error in SQL syntax becuase of the precceeding `'`. I have to decrypt the values again to display it. Does anybody have any suggestion on how to solve this issue? Any other encryption which doesn't returns ' or any way to store the encrypted value in database without removing the single quote?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL error when inserting data containing apostrophes (single quotes)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7600661/mysql-error-when-inserting-data-containing-apostrophes-single-quotes)

Comment: please read the question. i need to encrypt and then save the encrypted value in another table. i have to decrypt the value to display original text too.

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: is there any way to save the  encrypted value in database without removing the single quote? or is there any better solution for encryption?

Comment: Yes, you can save a value with a single quote. That was the point of my link.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The AES_ENCRYPT and AES_DECRYPT functions use and returns binary data that is most probably not usable in a copy-paste style when displayed in your browser (for example phpmyadmin).

You must pass return value of both functions to column that can store binary data, or encode the return value of the functions to hexadecimal representation.

To be able to copy-paste the data returned, you may use the following SQL query

```
SELECT HEX( AES_ENCRYPT( 'REMYA UNNIKRISHNAN', 'nirvana1987' ) ) AS encString
```

This will return:
275554F1BABE1AAEEE0F2AEBBDDEC146EFFA52F3C49174466EA5582FCF7E4AFA

Now to decrypt this value again in SQL, you can use the query

```
SELECT AES_DECRYPT( UNHEX( '275554F1BABE1AAEEE0F2AEBBDDEC146EFFA52F3C49174466EA5582FCF7E4AFA' ) , 'nirvana1987' )
```

This will give you back the original string.

Now to store the encrypted data in a column, the column must be BLOB, BINARY or their respective storage formats. Let us assume you have a column "encData" in table "myData". You may use the following query to store it into

```
INSERT INTO myData (encData) VALUES (AES_ENCRYPT( 'REMYA UNNIKRISHNAN', 'nirvana1987' ))
```

To retrieve the decrypted information stored in the table you may execute the query

```
SELECT AES_DECRYPT(encData, 'nirvana1987') as decString FROM myData
```

Comment: Or, in MySQL 5.6 and later, `TO_BASE64()` will result in a string that's somewhat shorter than `HEX()`, and then use `FROM_BASE64()` instead of `UNHEX()` to undo... but be sure to use a case-sensitive collation such as `ascii_bin` to store such a value, since base64 is case-sensitive. (+1)

Comment: Offtopic: it was actually good that you deleted your answer on that "finalizer" method question. Especially your comment about a need to nullify fields in subject was *completely* wrong. You should really study some material on such topics before trying to answer such questions. This one ... much better ;-)